# What does “disposal advance” mean?

Tags: phrases, sentence

I’m having trouble understanding the meaning of *disposal advance*. What do the following sentences mean?

> These are the amounts that we believe you are entitled to. You can derive no rights. The amounts are at your disposal advance.

Comment: Please add more examples, more context, or a link.  Not answerable as is.

Comment: @jwpat7, updated

Comment: [Google Ngrams finds no occurrences whatsoever of either *disposal advance* or *advance disposal*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disposal+advance%2Cadvance+disposal&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=4&smoothing=0&share=).  Sounds like some one-off error to me.

Comment: "disposal" goes with the prior words "at your".  The expression is "at your disposal" so the part that doesn't fit is "advance".  Up to that ambiguous part, it's saying the amounts are there for you to use or take.

Comment: Please add more context. Who wrote the text, where, and in what situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context it's impossible to say, but it sounds like a message from a bank worker who doesn't speak good English.

*Disposal* is sometimes used by banks to refer to money you have available to you; a current account is sometimes called a disposal account.

*Advance* may be a typo for *advice*, a word used by banks not for tips and suggestions but for telling you your account balance.

So perhaps *disposal advance* is a typo when they mean to tell you what your current account balance is.

---

Alternatively, there may be a missing "in":

> The
>    amounts are at your disposal [in] advance.

*At you disposal* means "available to you" and *in advance* means before time, before the usual time. This might fit with *You can derive no rights*, which is a disclaimer saying that you can't have any extra rights even with the offer they're making.

However, *You can derive no rights* doesn't sound like natural English either and may be a literal translation. My guess is from Dutch, as it turns up on many .nl websites.

Comment: Actually, this is the translation from Dutch:   Dit zijn de bedragen waar u volgens ons nu recht op hebt. U kunt hier geen rechten aan ontlenen. De vastgestelde bedragen staan op uw voorschotbeschikking.